# Can we search for a cell containing certain words and call the value beside it in excel?

Tags: excel, row

I have a excel file, each row is as below:

1. aaa_xxxx, 0.345,  bbb_xxxx, 0.456,  ccc_xxxx, 0.734,  ddd_xxxx,   0.544

If I would to call a cell containing "aaa" and call the value next to it (such as 0.345 as shown above), which function in excel may I use to call the value?

Comment: Is this one row or are there 4 rows?

Comment: The example is just one row, but I have to done this in multiple rows.

Comment: I just need to look one row at one time, and repeat this procedure in the next row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this formula:

```
=INDEX(A1:H1,MATCH("aaa*",A1:H1,0)+1)
```

[image]